# Read POST content in Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, meteor

I want to receive data with POST requests in my Meteor app. There's this code (server side):

```
__meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice (0, 0, {
  route: '/input',
  handle: function(req, res, next) {

    req.on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('ERROR', err);
    });

    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log('CHUNK');
    });

    req.on('end', function() {
      console.log('END');
    });


    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    });
    res.write('GOT IT!');
    res.end();

  }.future(),

});
```

The code does not work, callbacks with logs are never called. I've tried to move response code to `end` callback, but it doesn't help - the only change is that the request receives timeout instead of response.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me without the `future()` call.